# Backbone: the best way to communicate entities

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

What's the best way to connect different entities in Backbone App for my example:

I have some items on page (ex. shop items) and I need to make some actions with them. So I have a `Balance.Model` to keep a limit for some actions (ex. I can mark only N items with some flags, maybe colors). Of cause I have `Items.Collection` and `View.Actions` (to render menu links). Also I have `SelectedItems.Collection` to keep Item.Models, checked by checkboxes to actions.

So process some actions I'm need to do:

```
Action.onClick → Balance.checkLimits → SelectedItems.each(Item) → Item.processAction
```

I need to communicate Actions, Balance and SelectedItems collection to process action with checked items.
Whats the best way to do this? Triggers/listenTo? Keep some models inside another models?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like the responsibility for a controller that mitigates between views and models. AFAIK Backbone has no good standard method to do that. I would suggest taking a look at Backbone Marionette http://marionettejs.com/. It does a lot on the routing / views / application structure side for you that vanilla backbone has spared out in favor of flexibility. Check out http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/11/introduction-backbone-marionette/ for a brief introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... It seems that you are doing some very domain specific thing. For that I would extract the most generic thing into a concern and make that concern to work without views...

Then I would create a class which would contain the more concrete logic then mix in the previously created concern using this technique: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/classes_and_objects/mixins

Then if something happens on the UI like onClick I would intercept that in my view class then ask my concern to handle it...

That would separate the UI specific logic from the domain specific one + create a reusable concern.